# laravel 5.1 testing dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, laravel, testing, dojo

am having a problem testing a laravel 5.1 app forms which have input values that are conditional on other inputs, such that when the page is loaded the second input is disabled, then its enabled after the user chooses an option on a select control (which uses javascript to set the data store of the second select as well as enabling it) allowing them to enter input. The forms work on the browser, but when testing the disabled control isn't enabled even after explicitly selecting/typing in the first in put.

Here's my testing code

```
$this->visit('/forms/document')->submitForm('submit', ['username' => 'Superuser','password' => 'sample'])
        ->see('Upload Document')

        //test sending blank form
        ->submitForm('save',['owner' => ''])
        ->see('Name is Required')
        ->see('Type is Required')
        ->see('Owner is Required')
        ->see('File is Required')

        //test sending properly filled form
        ->type('user', '#type')
        ->type('1', '#owner')
        ->type('Test Document', 'name')
        ->attach(dirname(__FILE__).'/test_document.pdf','file')
        ->press('save')
        ->see('Test Document')
        ->see('Never')
        ->see(date("M d, Y"));
```

and a fragment of my form code

```
<tr>
            <td align="right">Attachment Type</td>
            <td >
                <select name='type' id='type' required='1' dojotype='dijit.form.FilteringSelect'
                value='{{$document->type}}'>
                    <option value=''>Please Select</option>
                    <option value='user'>System User</option>
                    <option value='company'>Company Document</option>
                    <option value='voucher'>Finance Voucher</option>
                    <option value='pipline'>Sales Voucher</option>
                    <script type="dojo/method" event="onChange">
                         children(this,'owner',null,"{{url('/')}}");
                    </script>
                </select>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Attached To (Owner)</td>
            <td>
                <select id='owner' name='owner' dojotype='dijit.form.FilteringSelect' disabled searchattr='name'></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan='2'>
                <button name='save' type='submit' dojotype='dijit.form.Button'>Save Document</button>
                <button name='new' type='submit' dojotype='dijit.form.Button'>Save and New</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

finally the javascript

```
//changing the data store of child from the value of the parent
function children(parent,child,parameters,url)
{
    var value = dijit.byId(parent).value.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0];
    if(parameters !==null){
        parameters = parameters.join('/');
    }
    var node = dijit.byId(child);
    node.set('disabled', false);
    node.set('displayedValue', '');
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({url: url+"/store/"+value+"/"+parameters});
    node.set('store', store);
}
```

While working with Integrated (as a separate package) and laravel 5.0 this was not a problem, but after I upgraded to 5.1 (because of multi dimensional form controls testing) the problem cropped up. I have tried everything I can think of but so far no joy. :( please help.

Comment: @Bogdan Under Laravel 5.0, the test directive to change the value of the 'type' would trigger the 'onChange' event which would fire the children() javascript function, which among other things removes the 'disabled' attribute of the owner field allowing it to be sent to the server alongside the other inputs. This capability broke down after installing Laravel 5.1

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I missed the fact that Selenium might be involved here. Ignore my previous comment :).

Comment: I had a similar problem using Laravel dusk and I guess I solved it with putting a delay in seconds before checking if the input or option is enabled or not.